# figure temporisation in Rmarkdown beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, beamer

Trying `Rmarkdown` for the first time, I can't find anywhere how to do some basic beamer operations. I'd like for example to make a figure appear after some text in a slide, or replace a figure by another one, still inside a frame.
How could I do this:

```
\only<1>{![](figureA.pdf)}
\only<2>{![](figureB.pdf)}
```

Can someone please give me the basics of slide temporisation with Rmarkdown?

Comment: rmarkdown is built on pandoc. thus see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer has redefined various macros, including `\includegraphics`, to accept overlay arguments. You can use them in rmarkdown like this:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
    keep_tex: true

---

# test

text

\includegraphics<+>[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics<+>[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
```